# NDSolve encounters non-numerical value for a derivative at t==0

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a relatively complicated set of DEs. If you wish to view the mathematical formulation of the problem, please have a look at the pdf contained in [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00773-014-0293-y) article. In my problem, propeller forces are omitted and there are a few other simplifications.

Excuse me for the following large block of code:

```
L = 320;
B = 58;
d = 20.8;
Vol = 312.600;
xG = 11.2;
Cb = 0.810;
HR = 15.80;
AR = 112.5;
Dp = 9.86;
radGyr = 0.25*L;
Uo = 15.5*0.514;
dens = 1023.6;
m = dens*Vol;
xR = -0.5*L;
IzG = m*radGyr^2;
eeta = Dp/HR;
(*Dimensionless, will be dimensionalized upon evaluation of total Forces*)
Xvv = -0.040;
Xvr = 0.002;
Xrr = 0.011;
Xvvvv = 0.771;
Yv = -0.315;
Yr = 0.083;
Yvvv = -1.607;
Yvvr = 0.379;
Yvrr = -0.391;
Yrrr = 0.008;
Nv = -0.317;
Nr = -0.049;
Nvvv = -0.030;
Nvvr = -0.294;
Nvrr = 0.055;
Nrrr = -0.013;
Ro = 0.022;
mx1 = 0.022;
my1 = 0.223;
Jz1 = 0.011;

(*with dimensions*)

mx = mx1*(1/2)*dens*L^2*d;
my = my1*(1/2)*dens*L^2*d;
Jz = Jz1*(1/2)*dens*L^4*d;

tP = 0.220;
tR = 0.387;
aH = 0.312;
xH1 = -0.464;
xH = xH1*L;
C1 = 2;
lR1 = -0.710;
epsilon = 1.09;
kappa = 0.50;
fa = 2.747;
ko = 0.2931;
k1 = -0.2753;
k2 =-0.1385;
wpo = 0.35;
xp1 = -0.55;
np = 18;
XH[t_]:=(1/2)*dens*L*d*U[t]^2*XH1[t];
YH[t_]:=(1/2)*dens*L*d*U[t]^2*YH1[t];
NH[t_]:=(1/2)*dens*L^2*d*U[t]^2*NH1[t];

(*1: non-dimensional*)
XH1[t_]:= -Ro+Xvv*(v1[t])^2+Xvr*v1[t]*r1[t]+Xrr*(r1[t])^2+Xvvvv*(v1[t])^4;
YH1[t_]:= Yv*v1[t]+Yr*r1[t]+Yvvv*(v1[t])^3+Yvvr*(v1[t])^2*r1[t]+Yvvr*v1[t]*(r1[t])^2+Yrrr*(r1[t])^3;
NH1[t_]:= Nv*v1[t]+Nr*r1[t]+Nvvv*(v1[t])^3+Nvvr*(v1[t])^2*r1[t]+Nvvr*v1[t]*(r1[t])^2+Nrrr*(r1[t])^3;

(*non-dimensional velocities*)
v1[t_]:=v[t]/U[t];
u1[t_]:=u[t]/U[t];
r1[t_]:=r[t]*L/U[t];
U[t_]:=Sqrt[(v[t])^2+(u[t])^2];
beta[t_]:=ArcTan[-v[t]/u[t]];
delta = 2*0.0873;

XR[t_]:=-(1-tR)*FN[t]*Sin[delta];
YR[t_]:=-(1+aH)*FN[t]*Cos[delta];
NR[t_]:=-(xR+aH*xH)*FN[t]*Cos[delta];

FN[t_]:=(1/2)*dens*AR*(UR[t])^2*fa*Sin[aR[t]];

UR[t_]:=Sqrt[(vR[t])^2+(uR[t])^2];
aR[t_]:=delta-vR[t]/uR[t];

vR[t_]:=U[t]*gammaR[t]*betaR[t];
betaR[t_]:=beta[t]-lR1*r1[t];
gammaR[t_]:=Piecewise[{{0.395,betaR[t]<0},{0.640,betaR[t]>0}}];


uR[t_]:=epsilon*u[t]*(1-wp)*Sqrt[eeta*(1+kappa*(Sqrt[1+8*KT[t]/(Pi*(JP[t])^2)]-1)^2+(1-eeta))];
KT[t_]:=k2*(JP[t])^2+k1*JP[t]+ko;
JP[t_]:=u[t]*(1-wp[t])/(Dp*np);
betaP[t_]:=beta[t]-xp1*r1[t];
C2[t_]:=Piecewise[{{1.6,betaP[t]<0},{1.1,betaP[t]>0}}];
wp[t_]:=(1-wpo)*(1-Exp[-C1*Abs[betaP[t]]]*(C2[t]-1));
X[t_]:=XH[t]+XR[t];
Y[t_]:=YH[t]+YR[t];
Nm[t_]:=NH[t]+NR[t]; 

surge=(m+mx)*u'[t]-(m+my)*v[t]*r[t]-xG*m*(r[t])^2 == X[t];
sway=(m+my)*v'[t]+(m+mx)*u[t]*r[t]+xG*m*r'[t] == Y[t];
yaw=(IzG+xG^2*m+Jz)*r'[t]+xG*m*(v'[t]+u[t]*r[t]) == Nm[t];

sol = NDSolve[{surge, sway, yaw, psi'[t]==r[t], u[0]==Uo, v[0]==0, r[0]==0, psi[0]==0.075},{u,v,r,psi},{t,0,1000}];
```

I keep getting the following error

```
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.
```

After reviewing my code multiple times I am under the impression that all values are well defined (of course, I could be wrong). I then thought that `Piecewise` functions `C2[t_]` and `gammaR[t_]` could cause discontinuities and be the root of this problem. I switched to constant numeric values for these quantities, but the problem persisted. Another thing I noticed while trying to solve this myself is, that despite the fact that I have set initial conditions within NDSolve, when inputing for example

```
v[0]
```

the output would be

```
 v[0]
```

instead of 0, which is the initial condition.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If I try to replace numerical values of functions in your equations, e.g. `surge /. {r[t] -> 1, v[t] -> 1, u[t] -> 1}`, you will notice that the expression depends on `wp` (not `wp[t]`) and that is undefined. The dependence is introduced in the definition of `ur`. I don't know whether that should be `wp[t]` everywhere, or perhaps `wp0`, or something else.

Comment: Notice that setting initial conditions in NDSolve through an equation (`==`) does not assign that value to `v[0]`, and that is correct behavior.

Comment: Correcting what you pointed out solved the issue. It should have been wp[t] . Thanks for helping! A new problem arose with discontinuities now but I should be able to tackle this. I also did not know that this was the expected NDSolve behavior in regards to initial conditions.

Comment: Glad it helped, and welcome to MMA Stack Exchange! I appreciate that in your first question you provided all the code necessary and that it was well-formatted, so help could be provided easily! I also wanted to let you know that your question is likely to be "closed" since it was more or less a syntax error. That's just normal housekeeping on this forum and does not indicate a judgment on the question itself. If you run into more trouble with the system you are working on, you are always welcome to ask a new separate question!

Comment: @DreamCream There is a typo on the line `uR[t_]:=` with `wp`. It whould be `wp[t]`. Then we have a message  `NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at t == 0.9792710474206497`; unable to continue.`. But we can handle this problem with some numerical methods.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I am actually having a different error after the typo correction `NDSolve::smpf: Failure to project onto the discontinuity surface when computing Filippov continuation at time 0.`.`  This is on version 13.1. I will try to solve this by using `WhenEvent` instead of piecewise functions or by turning off the DiscontinuityProcessing. If it doesn't work I might ask a different question. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: @DreamCream We can remove last equation `psi'[t] == r[t]` and solve it independently. Then use  `{t, 0, 100}`.